# How should I use WMPEqualizerSettingsCtrlClass in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wmplib

I use the following code:

```
WMPEqualizerSettingsCtrl eq = null;
eq.enhancedAudio = true;
```

But I get an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've set the `eq` object equal to `null` when declaring it. That is what produces the exception: you can't set the properties of an object that doesn't exist!

If you want to create an instance of the `WMPEqualizerSettingsCtrl` class, just use `new`:

```
WMPEqualizerSettingsCtrl eq = new WMPEqualizerSettingsCtrl();
eq.enhancedAudio = true;   // now eq exists, so it won't throw an exception!
```

I don't know exactly what the `WMPEqualizerSettingsCtrl` class is, but you might need to pass some parameters to the constructor. Those provide the class with additional information about exactly how you want it to be created.

Comment: Yes but WMPEqualizerSettingsCtrl is an interface, does not supports new clause !

Comment: @tkaz: Then you can't set properties on it. You can't instantiate interfaces. You have to find a class that *implements* that interface. Check the documentation to see how to create an object of that type.